# The same variables cause ARIMA produce different results

Tags: python, variables, machine-learning, statsmodels, arima

I have two identical set of variables:

```
np.all([
   np.all(a.y == b.y),
   np.all(a.X == b.X),
   np.all(a.o == b.o),
   type(a.y) == type(b.y),
   type(a.X) == type(b.X),
   type(a.o) == type(b.o)]
)
```

produce `True` (see the attached screenshot).

However, in the first case ARIMA is fitted, while in the second it ends up with an Error (see screenshot). Why does it happen?

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot from Jupyter Notebook]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found `statsmodels` package makes use of *base array* of *numpy array* (`ndarray.base`), which can lead to distorted results. To avoid this effect, we need to feed both endogenous and exogenous variables as `array.copy()`. Hope it helps other researchers.`